# Rename and move images to a destination directory based on a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

As a followup to [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223641/python-script-to-rename-images-based-on-descriptions-in-a-text-file) question, I removed the `Repository` class and do the copy in the `Folder` class.

Suppose I have the following image directories under the Pictures directory of a Windows user profile:

```
C:\Users\Kiska\Pictures\Computers
    - comp-amd-21343.jpg
    - 12345.jpg
C:\Users\Kiska\Pictures\Cars
    - car-random.jpg
    - 54321.jpg
```

In each of those directories, they're are two images each. Notice that the names aren't reflective of what the images depicts.

My script will take a source directory, rename the images based on the folder name and the order in which it was renamed, and move it to a destination directory.

So the above images would be renamed:

```
computers_1.jpg
computers_2.jpg

cars_1.jpg
cars_2.jpg
```

**Source.txt**:

```
Computers
Cars
```

**Folder.py:**

```
import os
import shutil

class Folder:

    def __init__(self, directory: str):
        self._check_if_str_parameters_are_empty(parameter=directory, error_message="Directory cannot be empty") 
        self._directory = directory.strip()

    def _check_if_str_parameters_are_empty(self, parameter, error_message):
        if not parameter:
            raise ValueError(error_message)

    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        return self._directory

    def get_lst_of_files(self) -> list:
        return os.listdir(self._directory)

    def copy_files_with(self, extension: str, to_location: "Folder"):
        if self == to_location:
            raise ValueError("Source and Destination cannot be the same")
        if "." in extension:
            raise ValueError("Extension is incorrect type")

        lst_of_images_in_source = os.listdir(self._directory)
        number_of_images_in_source = len(lst_of_images_in_source)

        print(f"Number of images: {number_of_images_in_source}")

        if number_of_images_in_source:
            number_of_images_in_destination = len(to_location.get_lst_of_files()) + 1

            for number, image in enumerate(lst_of_images_in_source, start=number_of_images_in_destination):
                source_image = os.path.join(self._directory, image)
                destination_image = os.path.join(to_location.name,
                                            self._construct_destination_string(self._get_base_name(str_to_split=self._directory), 
                                            number, extension))
                print(f"{source_image} will be renamed to {destination_image}")
                shutil.move(source_image,  destination_image)
        else:
            print("No images to rename")

    def _get_base_name(self, str_to_split: str) -> str:
        return str_to_split.split("\\")[-1]

    def _construct_destination_string(self, image_name: str, current_number: str, extension: str) -> str:
        return "{0}_{1}.{2}".format(image_name.lower().replace(" ", "_"), current_number, extension)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Folder):
            return (self._directory) == (other._directory)
        return NotImplemented

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._directory)
```

**Main.py:**

```
import os
from Folder import Folder

def main():

    source_txt = "source.txt"
    source_pictures = "{0}\\{1}".format(os.getenv("USERPROFILE"), "Pictures")
    destination_pictures = None
    extension = "jpg"

    try:

        if not destination_pictures:
            raise ValueError("Please provide a valid destination path.")

        if os.path.getsize(source_txt):
            if os.path.exists(source_txt) and os.path.exists(destination_pictures):
                with open(source_txt) as folder_reader:
                    for folder in folder_reader:
                        source_folder = os.path.join(source_pictures, folder)
                        if os.path.exists(source_folder):
                            source = Folder(directory=source_folder)
                            destination_folder = os.path.join(destination_pictures, folder)
                            os.makedirs(destination_folder, exist_ok=True)
                            destination = Folder(directory=destination_folder)
                            source.copy_files_with(extension=extension, to_location=destination)
                        else:
                            print(f"{folder} doesn't exist")
            else:
                print("Source file or Destination drive is missing")
        else:
            print("Source file is empty")

    except(ValueError, OSError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I removed all the custom validation because as pointed out in my previous question, it was unnecessary.

**Areas of concern**:

- The `finally` block of the `try` statement has the `pass` under it. I handle the exceptions, and use the `with` statement to read the file, so I don't really know what should go there.
- I use type hinting, but I should also use docstrings and comments, but I didn't add them to save space.

Comment: Am I understanding your code correctly? Are you basically copying all files from `src/{name}/*` to `dst/{name}_{i}`?

Comment: @Peilonrayz - Not all the files in Pictures, just the ones specified in the text file, it gets renamed and placed in the equivalent destination folder.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in a rush so this is half baked :(

- It's best if you provide everything, currently your code isn't PEP 8 compliant due to you removing the docstrings. Some people may moan at you for this.
- You should prefer guard statements over `if` `else` statements when possible. You can easily change `if os.path.getsize(source_txt)` to use a `not` which would reduce the amount of indentation and reduce the complexity to read.
- You seem to have half baked error handling and I wouldn't be surprised if you're duplicating errors you can get from `open` and `pathlib`.
- I don't think you need a `Folder` class. If you use `pathlib` then everything you need should be fairly simple. I'm probably missing a couple of features but I think what you want is as simple as the below code.

```
from pathlib import Path


def main(source, src, dst, extensions):
    src = Path(src)
    dst = Path(dst)
    with open(source) as folders:
        for folder_name in folders:
            for i, file in enumerate(
                file
                for file in (src / folder_name).iterdir()
                if file.suffix in extensions
            ):
                shutil.move(file,  dst / f'{folder_name}_{i}{file.suffix}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main(
            "source.txt",
            "{0}\\{1}".format(os.getenv("USERPROFILE"), "Pictures"),
            None,
            (".jpg",),
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise SystemExit(1) from None
```