# Rename and move images to a destination directory based on a text file followup

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my third (and hopefully final) time re-writing this [program](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/224159/rename-and-move-images-to-a-destination-directory-based-on-a-text-file). It was recommended I use `Pathlib` and it simplified my code, it's easier to read and understand than the first two monstrosities.

I also changed the way it functions, instead of the user providing a text file, the user creates a directory called `Repository`, which contains sub directories of images that will be renamed, and a destination directory (`R:\Pictures` for me).

Suppose I have the following directories under `Repository`:

```
C:\Users\Kiska\Repository\Computers
   - comp-amd-12342.jpg
   - 7546345233-pcmag.jpg

C:\Users\Kiska\Repository\Landscape
   - land-345345.jpg
   - end-field.jpg
```

The program will move and rename it like this:

```
R:\Pictures\Pictures\Computers
   - computers_1.jpg
   - computers_2.jpg

R:\Pictures\Pictures\Landscape
   - landscape_1.jpg
   - landscape_2.jpg
```

**Code**:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

def check_if_folder_exists(folder : Path):
    if not Path.exists(folder):
        raise FileNotFoundError("{0} is not available".format(folder))


def main():      


    try:

        repository = Path("{0}\\{1}".format(os.getenv("USERPROFILE"), "Repository"))
        desination_root = Path("R:\\Pictures")

        check_if_folder_exists(folder=repository)
        check_if_folder_exists(folder=desination_root)

        for folder in repository.iterdir():
            destination = Path(desination_root).joinpath(folder.stem)
            Path.mkdir(destination, exist_ok=True)

            start = len(os.listdir(destination)) + 1

            for number, image in enumerate(folder.iterdir(), start=start):
                image_name = "{0}_{1}{2}".format(folder.stem.lower().replace(" ","_"), number,image.suffix)
                destination_image = Path(destination).joinpath(image_name)
                print(f"{image} will be named {destination_image}")
                shutil.move(image, destination_image)


    except(ValueError, FileNotFoundError, OSError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You have lots of unneeded empty lines, they also hinder readability.
- `fn(arg=value)` is abnormal. It's common to use `fn(value)`. It's common only to use the former when the argument is a keyword or default argument.
- You don't need to make a path another path.

  > ```
  > desination_root = Path("R:\\Pictures")
  > destination = Path(desination_root).joinpath(folder.stem)
  > ```
- [`Path.mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir) isn't a static method, and so it's abnormal to use it as `Path.mkdir(my_path)` rather than `my_path.mkdir()`.
- `check_if_folder_exists` isn't needed as `repository.iterdir` and `destination.mkdir` will error if they don't exist.

  It should also be noted that you can pass `parents=True` to `Path.mkdir` to automatically create the folder if it doesn't exist, rather than force the user to do that.
- It's better if you make another function that moves the files, and one, `main`, that passes it the values. Preferably `main` would be changed to not use static values and get the values from a config file.
- `finally` isn't needed.
- You should raise a `SystemExit(1)` or use `sys.exit(1)` if there is an error. They both do the same thing which notifies the system that the program failed. It didn't run without problems.
- Given that generating a name that doesn't conflict with existing files is not a simple one-liner I'd recommend you move it out into a function.

  I should note that it may overwrite files, if you have a folder with `file_1.png` and `file_3.png` your code's going to overwrite `file_3.png`, but not have a `file_2.png`.

You changed away from some of the above, and so I'd recommend you think about the differences, which is easier to re-use, which is easier to read, which performs the correct action in the situation. If you don't know what the difference is even with my explanation, such as with `SystemExit(1)`, then you should look up what it does.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import shutil


def gen_name(path, number):
    orig_name = path.parent.name.lower().replace(" ", "_")
    return f"{orig_name}_{number}{path.suffix}"


def move_files(src, dest):
    for folder in Path(src).iterdir():
        destination = Path(dest) / folder.stem
        destination.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
        start = len(os.listdir(destination)) + 1
        for number, image in enumerate(folder.iterdir(), start=start):
            image_name = gen_name(image, number)
            destination_image = destination / image_name
            print(f"{image} will be named {destination_image}")
            shutil.move(image, destination_image)


def main():
    try:
        move_files(
            "{0}\\{1}".format(os.getenv("USERPROFILE"), "Repository"),
            "R:\\Pictures",
        )
    except(ValueError, FileNotFoundError, OSError) as error:
        print(error)
        raise SystemExit(1) from None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I think it could make more sense for `gen_name` to be a closure, as then it can correctly handle existing files. I won't change how the code functions, but will show how it could be implemented.

```
def gen_name_builder(folder):
    orig_name = folder.name.lower().replace(" ", "_")
    number = len(os.listdir(destination))
    def gen_name(file):
        nonlocal number
        number += 1
        return f"{orig_name}_{number}{path.suffix}"
    return name


def move_files(src, dest):
    for folder in Path(src).iterdir():
        destination = Path(dest) / folder.stem
        destination.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
        gen_name = gen_name_builder(destination)
        for image in folder.iterdir():
            image_name = gen_name(image)
            destination_image = destination / image_name
            print(f"{image} will be named {destination_image}")
            shutil.move(image, destination_image)
```

Comment: Is it okay to use an `if/else` statement in the for loop responsible for moving the images? Check if it exists, if not, move it, if it does, leave it, but notify the user with a print statement

Comment: @Kiska Please look over the additional code I added to my answer. You should be able to handle if an item exists with that name in `gen_name`. Yes, you can use an `if`. As a hint I would use a `while`.

Comment: The docs on `Path.mkdir()` is misleading, it uses it as a static method.

Comment: @Kiska I'm not seeing the docs use [`Path.mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir) as a static method. I've checked the other languages too, and they also don't show that. I'm sorry that this has caused some confusion.

Comment: Right at the top in yellow where you can link to it  `Path.mkdir(mode=0o777, parents=False, exist_ok=False)`.

Comment: @Kiska Ok, I get the confusion now. That isn't an example of how to use the method, it tells you where the method is defined, `Path.mkdir`, and shows the arguments it has, with any defaults they have. If you look at [`Path.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.open) you can see the same thing, but it has an example showing it used in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

- Give `main` method a more meaningful name. It is always better than a generic `main`.
- Make `repository` and `destination_root` be parameters of the method which is now called `main`;
- If you use python version that supports f-strings, be consistent, use them everywhere e.g. `f'{folder} is not available'`;
- `finally: pass` does not have any effect so if you are not going to put any logic there, it can be omitted;
- regarding the `start` parameter passed to `enumerate`: can you guarantee that if that the destination folder contains 1 picture, it will be called *xxxxx_1.jpg*, not *xxxxx_2.jpg* or *xxxxx_27.jpg*?
- I would also extract `folder.stem.lower().replace(" ","_")` into a separate variable which can get some meaningful name (which can be then used in f-string) to enhance reading;

Comment: The `start` parameter is the number of images already present + 1 so if 4 images already exist in the destination, we start at 5.

Comment: @Kiska Okay, let me rephrase, what would happen if before you run the program `R:\Pictures\Pictures\Computers` contained **one**  file with the name `computers_2.jpg`?

Comment: Ah! I see now what you mean. I should check first if the filename is already present in the destination directory.